# "Could not create directory" Error when installing plugins - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

The back story: I transferred all the data from wordpress.com site to a self hosted site. That messed with a lot of the images in the posts etc. (not displaying) so naturally I just started messing with things (I don't really know what I'm doing). After changing a bunch of file permissions (with FileZilla) the images started to work but now all my plugins stopped working. I deleted them and tried to reinstall and I get this error:

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> Could not create directory. /homepages/35/d579288618/htdocs/kevin-heinrich.com/kevin-heinrich/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/
>
> Plugin install failed.

I don't really know where the **"/homepages/35/d579288618/htdocs/..."** part of the error is coming from...

I have tried changing ALL my file permissions to 777, no luck.
I tried manually downloading a plugin and putting it into the plugins folder via FTP, no luck. (The folder is in there but nothing appears on my dashboard).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm afraid to keep messing around on my own because well, I break things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow what a simple problem. After literally a month of banging my head against the wall...

My problem was that my plugins folder was in my uploads folder NOT my wp-content directory. I moved and boom solved.

Hopefully any other idiot who tinkers where he/she shouldn't might find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue. Check that `user` and `group` in /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf are set to `www-data`. By default it's `http`.